# Read geotagging data from iphone photos exif data

Tags: iphone, photos, camera, gps

I shoot photos with my iPhone and localization services are active.

When I open a photo from my Mac Preview (tools > show inspector > exif) I can't see any geotagging data.

BUT, when I open the image with my Mac Photos it correctly positions a pin on a map.

So, my question is: why I can't see geotagging data (GPS latitude and longitude) if it is clear they are written somewhere in the image? If they weren't, how could the map position the pin correctly?

I tried various services online but I can't see any geodata either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an EXIF viewer on your Mac (which may show the location on a map or the actual GPS coordinates), I would suggest [Image Exif Editor](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/image-exif-editor/id574607554?mt=12). If you look at the screenshots for this app, it clearly shows the GPS coordinates. If you are looking for something similar for your iPhone or iPad, I would recommend doing a search in the App Store using the search criteria "EXIF."

Comment: I think I found an answer: when you connect an iPhone to your Mac, Mac starts Photos, so you can import your pics. Now: if, from Photos, you drag an image to your desktop, it looks like it looses geodata. Instead, if you export a photo using the export menu item and you choose to export location data too, there's no such an issue

Comment: Try enabling “Include location information for published items” in Photos preferences. Last I checked this also applied to drag-and-drop. https://blog.houdah.com/2015/12/keeping-geotags-dragging-images-apple-photos/